# IIS AppPool Permissions to inspect Domain Group Membership?

Tags: windows, iis

This seems an absurdly trivial question, but darned if I could work out the answer on my own: Given an IIS 7.x or later application running under a local application pool identity, how is that identity able to inspect group memberships across the network without inherently having network access?

Put another way, say I have an app called "SuperDuperApp", and it runs under a local IIS AppPool identity called "SuperDuperApp." I define the app's permissions to include users from "SomeDomain\SuperDuperAppUsers". Given that the IIS AppPool\SuperDuperApp identity isn't going to have network access, how will it ever be able to determine if a given domain user is a member of "SomeDomain\SuperDuperAppUsers"?

Comment: "I define the app's permissions to include users from ..." How? Different ways will invoke different Windows API under the hood, and that specific API will verify if the caller has the rights to do so. As application pool identities are virtual accounts, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities to connect to external resources (like database), Windows automatically uses the machine account instead.

Comment: @LexLi Using the IIS manager, I'll right-click on a site, click "Edit Permissions," and add/remove users and/or groups from that dialog as appropriate.

Comment: @LexLi That reference is actually exactly what I was trying to find. It answers the question spot-on. If you want to post that as an answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from the comment,

As application pool identities are virtual accounts, they are not used to connect to external resources (like database). More information can be found from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).

Windows automatically uses the machine account in those cases. So when you configure file share or database, make sure the machine account has access to it.

Comment: Thanks again. I hate it when subtleties like this (that I think I should long-since know) bite me sometimes.

Comment: @DavidW well, IIS/Windows has many things documented badly, so everyone (including me) is learning it :)